# asp.net mvc in container in an azure windows app service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, docker

Is it possible to run a full ASP.NET MVC application (not .NET Core) in a Docker (or other) container in an Azure App Service, and if so, what are pointers to documentation for such?

This says yes on ASP.NET MVC in a container:
[Can we deploy an asp.net mvc 4 app to docker with windows container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642876/can-we-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc-4-app-to-docker-with-windows-container)

And this says yes on .NET Core in a docker container in a linux App Service
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/new-docker-tools-for-visual-studio/

However I haven't been able to find a yes on:
ASP.NET MVC + Container + App Service

Or can the two references above be combined to safely infer that the configuration I'm looking for is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitive answer from Microsoft

"As of today (1/5/17), App Service doesn’t support containers on Windows, but it does on Linux (which is in preview) and the only version of ASP.NET that supports Linux is ASP.NET Core."

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3688feb3-3df1-4822-aab1-03c8271e16bf/aspnet-mvc-container-in-an-azure-app-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Windows App service is not offering containers, but why would you need a container, when basically it is a container (sort of). It's a PaaS service, where you have no control over the IIS which is offered as a service to you. But if you really want containers use Azure Container Service or Virtual Machines. To be honest, I do not see any reason to use containers if you are aiming at Azure App Service, why introduce another management level?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14683206)

Comment: @Shawn well, care to read the question and my answer. He asks if it is possible to use windows containers and Azure App Service, the answer is not at this time.

Comment: @4c74356b41 "not at this time"...do you have a confirming link for that?

Comment: While I agree the "why" is not relevant, the reason is that a licensee customer might want greater isolation and control.  If there are many licensees, it might be easier to deploy the app in containers, both on premise or to Azure.  While VM is possible they require more management overhead.  I think the choice of going to containers comes down to what constitutes "many" in terms of licensees.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I read this as a comment and then a question asking why they are trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service Linux (Preview) provides Container support on Linux VMs.

You can follow this post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/new-docker-tools-for-visual-studio/

You can try to run Asp.Net MVC in a container and post the result here.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx